# iOS bar button item and text field delegate method order

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uitextfielddelegate, target-action

I have a `viewController` that is presented modally, and when the cancel `leftBarButtonItem` is pressed I want a certain `property` to be set to `nil` before the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldEndEditing` gets called.

I was able to do this when I was using `unwindSegue` from storyboard, using `prepareForSegue`, but when I set the `target-action`for the `leftBarButtonItem` programmatically, `textFieldShouldEndEditing` gets called before the action method gets called for the `leftBarButtonItem`. Does anyone know how to call a method before `textFieldShouldEndEditing` gets called? Thanks!

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter or Delegates.

Comment: Did you try calling method from viewWillDisappear of the view controller?

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is called much later than textFieldShouldEndEditing.